# How to add a build phase in a project template?

Tags: templates, scripting, xcode4, targets

I'm trying to add a Run Script Build Phase to a target in a custom Project Template for Xcode 4.

Does anyone have any examples, tutorials, or tips on how to do this?

I'm assuming that this will be done in TemplateInfo.plist - but my searches are comming up fruitless.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After quite a lot of trial-and-error I've worked it out. This is the extra key needed in the TemplateInfo.plist. This adds a script that will run after the other default build phases.

```
<key>Targets</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>BuildPhases</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Class</key>
                <string>ShellScript</string>
                <key>ShellPath</key>
                <string>/bin/sh</string>
                <key>ShellScript</key>
                <string># Just a comment</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: and what if I wanted to have it run before the Compile Sources phase?

Comment: Any tips on running this script before the compile phase?

Comment: To make it run before, you should open the ancestors til you find the other build phases. Then you just put it before the Source build phase.

Comment: @Wex Do you know how to define the input and output files?

Comment: FYI: you can actually rename the Script's title within XCode by specifying the key "Name" (<key>Name</key><string>Some Title</string>)

Answer (score 1):

To answer to @Paulo Faria question, I found a way to add input and output files to a Run script phase (My template uses [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift), which requires input and output files):

```
<key>Targets</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>BuildPhases</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Class</key>
                <string>ShellScript</string>
                <key>ShellPath</key>
                <string>/bin/sh</string>
                <key>Name</key>
                <string>R.swift</string>
                <key>ShellScript</key>
                <string>"$PODS_ROOT/R.swift/rswift" generate "$SRCROOT/R.generated.swift"</string>
                <key>InputFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string>$TEMP_DIR/rswift-lastrun</string>
                </array>
                <key>OutputFiles</key>
                <array>
                    <string>$SRCROOT/R.generated.swift</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```