# How can I mark "To Do" comments in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Currently I'm working on an iOS based Image Manipulation task.

#### Problem:

I'm working on different modules. So If I need to add something in a module in future, I want to mark it as a To do note.
Are there any other macros or similar to add a to do note in Xcode ?

#### I tried:

For this currently I'm using `#pragma` like:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark To do: Add the Image processing methods.
```

#### I got:

But it lists in the Method section like:

[image: To Do]

#### What I actually need:

The issue is, it's listed under the methods list so sometimes I forgot to remove this from the section also it's very difficult to find it in entire source code. (Searching #pragma results to show entire lists)

#### Technical Details:

I'm using Xcode Version 4.6.2 .

Comment: How do I get to that particular view where Xcode lists all the methods, pragma marks and TODO annotations?

Comment: @Mischa: Check my answer, It's under the method listing bar.

Comment: I did check your answer and did not find a hint how to show that pop-up. But I think I found it now: It's on top of the code editor in that "navigation" bar, right?

Comment: Btw: Is there any way to show all of the project's TODOs at once?

Comment: @Mischa: Yes it's on the top of code editor, and in my knowledge there is no way to display all to do comments at once (Instead of searching the whole project)

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I got it.

Writing comment like:

```
// TODO: Do something
```

Will do the trick.

I got something like:

[image: TO DO]

---

**Also there is a lot of options like**:

1. `// FIXME: Midhun`
2. `// ???: Midhun`
3. `// !!!: Midhun`
4. `// MARK: Midhun`

Comment: you can also use //FIXME: or #warning. when you use #warning, you got a warning in Xcode and you can jump directly to that part.

Comment: Isn't that what @Dev2rights posted an hour before you?  Why don't you accept his answer?

Comment: @trojanfoe: yes. But I got a more apt solution for me //MARK: and #warning. That's why I didn't accepted it

Comment: Well `// FIXME`, `// MARK` and `#warning` aren't the same as `// TODO` and so that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @trojanfoe: Ya, that's true. But when I use #warning each time, i'll get a warning so I never forgot the place where I put it also. Always remember the pending things (It's not same as TODO but for me it can solve my headache)

Comment: @Daij-Djan: I also said the difficult of using #pragma, because often I forgot in which module I put it. So #warning is easy for me to remind this

Comment: yes, it sure is :) im in no way disagreeing ;) I mearly stated how I saw it -- same as trojonfoe

Comment: @MidhunMP Can you publish all the options available if there others ? Or at least publish a link on the source document ? Thanks

Comment: @Domsou: Currently there are no other options available rather than the listed ones. I'll update my answer if I get any.

Comment: These do not appear to work inside functions as of Xcode 5.1.

Comment: I used this often, but now, with Xcode 6.4 it doesn't appear to work for me any more. Anyone else?

Comment: @ThomasTempelmann: I'm using Xcode 6.4, and it is still working for me (In swift these markers are the only available alternative for #pragma, so it should work)

Comment: what is the source of these marks? and what does it mean !!! or ???

Answer (score 135):

```
// TODO: the thing todo
```

Is how you show todo tasks.

Comment: You can also use `// FIX: Everything crashes all the time` to make it easier get back to parts of your code that generate issues using the Jump Bar.

Comment: Strangely using this does not show the comment in XCode 5.1.1

Comment: 2 more markers that seem relevant here are #warning and #error http://i.imgur.com/KVjrVwG.png

Comment: Nitpick: Put a space between the `//` and `TODO:`.  For example:  `// TODO: Read this from prefs`.  If you review documentation of the Swift and Objective C languages, this space convention is fairly consistently followed.

Answer (score 48):

Using the

```
//TODO: some thing here
```

works if all you want to do is to look at the list of todos in the drop down

If you want to be intrusive you can use `#warning` marks instead:

```
#warning this will create a compiler warning.
```

And when you build the app you will get a compiler warning (a yellow triangle, not a compiler error) which is a little more "in your face" about reminding you of things you need to do.

Comment: I think `#warning` is the best solution because it will warn you at compile time. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

With the script below your can see all required tags like warnings.

1. Select your project in the Project Navigator
2. Open the target in the sidebar and move to the "Build Phases" tab
3. Click on "+" sign
4. Select "New Run Script Build Phase"
   [image: Script adding]
5. Add below script to "Run Script"
   [image: Ready Script]
   The script:

   ```
   KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|DevTeam:|XXX:"
   find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
   ```

[image]

Original answer was taken from [Here](https://coderwall.com/p/bfd0dq)

Another alternative is [XToDo](https://github.com/trawor/XToDo) plugin for Xcode.

Comment: great solution, is there a way to exclude all the pod files? there are a couple of Todos oder Mixmes in my used extensions?

Comment: found a solution by myself in this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/37157027/6003494 the script is: `KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "." \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "./Pods/*" -print0 | 
  xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | 
  perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"`

Answer (score 9):

I started with

> `// TODO: Implement bubble sort`.

Then I joined a large project and sometimes I needed a todo to live longer than a WIP commit and so to distinguish my todos from my peers I name spaced my todo with my initials:

> `// TODO: SM: Implement bubble sort`

Sometimes I wanted more visibility so I started to use pragma warnings in some places.

> `#warning Implement bubble sort`

One day I decided to turn on hard mode by adding `-Werror` to my cflags. Unfortunately this makes pragma warnings useless because they prevent compilation. And so I went back to using `// TODO:` until Jeff Nadeau told me that I can put

> `-Wno-error=#warnings`

in my cflags so as to not treat pragma warnings as errors. So now `#warning` and `-Werror` can live along side each other.

Answer (score 7):

You can use XToDo plugin

https://github.com/trawor/XToDo

[image: use ctrl+t to trigger the List Window on/off]

use ctrl+t to trigger the List Window on/off

[image: Toolbar exemple]

Easy install with alcatraz 
use ctrl+t to trigger the List Window on/off

Comment: Was scrolling down to suggest that, completely recommend.

Answer (score 5):

I tend to write exactly:

```
//TODO: Blah blah blah
```

Then I just do a **COMMAND-SHIFT-F** and look for "//TODO".

Using the file outline drop down will only show you TODOs for the current file, but I tend to want to see my project's TODO status.

Rough solution, but it does it's job.

Answer (score 2):

I split up the recognized tokens into Warnings and Errors for my own use, thought I would share it here:

```
KEYWORDS="STUB:|WARNING:|TODO:|FIXME:|DevTeam:|\?\?\?:" 
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/*" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/1: warning: \$1/"

KEYWORDS="ERROR:|XXX:|\!\!\!:" 
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/*" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/1: error: \$1/"
ERROR_OUTPUT=`find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/*" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/1: error: \$1/"`

exit ${#ERROR_OUTPUT}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method, slightly outside the box, if you don't want to clutter up the methods listing bar, is to use a convention within comments like `//Todo:` and when you want to address them en-masse, simply select the Find Navigator, match case and search for `//Todo:`

I prefer this as I don't like the methods drop down looking like spagetti-code. And yes, I often have lots of Todo:'s ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
#error
```

and

```
#warning
```

are also used in C programming