# Show TODO comments as warnings excluding the Pods folder

Tags: xcode, bash, cocoapods

I have a script to show all my `//TODO:` comments which looks like this:

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"

find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -print0 | 
  xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | 
  perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

I want to exclude my `Pods` folder, therefore I have added `-not -path "./Pods/*"`:

```
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "./Pods/*" -print0 | 
  xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | 
  perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

This works as expected when I try it on the Terminal (replacing `"${SRCROOT}"` with `"."`), but when it is run by Xcode it uses the `Pods` folder as well.

How can I exclude the folder in the build phase script?

**Final version**

This seems to work:

```
KEYWORDS="TODO:|FIXME:|\?\?\?:|\!\!\!:"
find "." \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "./Pods/*" -print0 | 
  xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | 
  perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/ warning: \$1/"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `find .` and set the *working directory* of the build script to `${SRCROOT}`.  This should allow the `.` in `-not -path "./Pods/*"` to make sense to `find`.

Comment: Now I do `cd ${SRCROOT}` `find "." ...` and it works, but I still don't understand why. Shouldn't it be the same?

Comment: Because of the mismatch between `${SRCROOT}` and `.`.  You are telling `find` to look in `/path/to/project` and so there is no `./Pods/` found (it will be `/path/to/project/Pods` or somesuch) and so the test will fail.  There is no need to do `(cd ${SRCROOT}; find ...)` as that functionality is covered by Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get it to work correctly without using ${SRCROOT} macro, as you couldn't click on the warning to go to the source line.

I split up the recognized tokens into Warnings and Errors for my own use, thought I would share it here:

```
KEYWORDS="STUB:|WARNING:|TODO:|FIXME:|DevTeam:|\?\?\?:" 
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/*" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/1: warning: \$1/"

KEYWORDS="ERROR:|XXX:|\!\!\!:" 
find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/*" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/1: error: \$1/"
ERROR_OUTPUT=`find "${SRCROOT}" \( -name "*.h" -or -name "*.m" -or -name "*.swift" \) -not -path "${SRCROOT}/Pods/*" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep --with-filename --line-number --only-matching "($KEYWORDS).*\$" | perl -p -e "s/($KEYWORDS)/1: error: \$1/"`

exit ${#ERROR_OUTPUT}
```