# How do I use #pragma warnings while leaving on -Werror "Treat warnings as errors" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, gcc, clang, pragma, gcc-warning

I like the `-Werror` "Treat warnings as errors" cflag but I also like to use [warning pragmas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16913055/how-can-i-mark-to-do-comments-in-xcode) as a reminder to fix up things after compiling but before committing my changes. Is there a way to use both as the same time?

Answer (score 1):

[Jeff Nadeau](https://twitter.com/jnadeau/status/885281520180633600):

> @SteveMoser you can put -Wno-error=#warnings in your cflags and
>   they’ll be relaxed back down to warnings. (Which is exactly what we
>   do, project-wide)

[image]